# WPF update textblock from different window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datacontext

I have a window called RolledPaper.xaml with a textblock called SequenceValue.
SequenceValue is defined in another window called CounterSettings.xaml by typing in a textbox  called SequenceRequested. I would like to have SequenceValue be always in sinch with SequenceRequested.
I tryed and failed using the same datacontext for both windows.
here it is the code for RolledPaper.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Numbering3.View.RolledPaper"
            WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    BorderBrush="LightGray"
    BorderThickness="5"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Numbering3.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Numbering3.ViewModel"
    xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Numbering3.Helper"
    xmlns:vo="clr-namespace:Numbering3.ViewModel"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RolledPaper"  Height="750" Width="1218"
    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}"
    DataContextChanged="Rolledpaper_DataContextChanged">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModelRolledPaper/>
</Window.DataContext>


 <TextBlock x:Name="SequenceValue" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="72,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Text="{Binding _SequenceValueToShow.SequenceValuetoShow, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=NNN, TargetNullValue=NNN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>


</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
    public partial class RolledPaper : Window
{
    public RolledPaper()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        SaveKeeper.fromMain = false;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate { this.DragMove(); };
        DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(Rolledpaper_DataContextChanged);
    }
```

the CounterSetting window:

```
<Window x:Class="Numbering3.View.CounterSettings"
```

...
...

```
    <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModelCounterSettings/>
</Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Margin="0,-19,-0.4,0">
<TextBox  x:Name="SequenceRequested"  PreviewTextInput="SequenceValidationTextBox" MaxLength="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="154,324,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
              Text="{Binding Path=_SequenceValueToShow.SequenceValueToKeep,   FallbackValue='NNN', TargetNullValue ='NNN', Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="SequenceRequested_TextChanged" />
    </Grid>
```

its code behind:

```
 public partial class CounterSettings : Window
{
    public CounterSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate { this.DragMove(); };

        DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(CounterSettings_DataContextChanged);

    }
```

And the SequeneValue class:

```
   public class SequenceValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public string SequenceValueToKeep
    {
        get
        {
            return _sequenceValueToKeep=_sequenceProcessor.GetSequence();
        }

        set
        {
            if (_sequenceValueToKeep != value)
            {
                __sequenceValueToKeep = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SequenceValueToKeep");
            }
        }
    }
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

I need to put a value in the textbox of countersetting =>string Sequencevalue.SequenceValueToKeep is updated => textblock in RolledPaper window shows Sequencevalue.SequenceValueToKeep  .

Thank you.

Comment: Where is `_SequenceValueToShow` defined?

Comment: @Ackdari in the ViewModelRolledPaper.xaml, I did not put it because I keep it short:      public SequenceValue _SequenceValueToShow { get; set; } and in the constructor    _SequenceValueToShow = new SequenceValue(_sequenceProcessor, _matrixProcessor);

Comment: TO be clear, if I close the RolledPaper window go to another one  and come back the RolledPaper page is updated and the textblock shows the new value. CounterSetting Window does not close the Rolledpaper window.

Comment: @Doraemon: How are ViewModelCounterSettings and ViewModelRolledPaper defined? Why don't you use the same view model for both windows?

Comment: @mm8 they are 2 different windows so I used 2 different viewmodels and 2 different views.

Comment: @Doraemon but how do these two comunicate? Also why is the Mode on the `TextBlock` Binding `TwoWay`?

Comment: @Ackdari the communication between the 2 is the problem exactly, the twoway is just because I copy paste it. How can I update the textblock by writing in the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Solutio 1:

You can use one Static ViewModel to get the to to know each other.

in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    ...
    <MainViewModel x:Key="mainViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

and then in CounterSetting.xaml

```
<Window otherProperties=...
        DataContext="{Binding ViewModelCounterSettings, Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}}"/>
```

and in RolledPaper.xaml

```
<Window otherProperties=...
        DataContext="{Binding ViewModelRolledPaper, Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}}"/>
```

The MainViewModel does inits your two ViewModel and makes them accessible as properties and also gives the the same instance of `SequenceValue`

Solution 2:

Create an object of `SequenceValue` as an static resource, like

```
<Application.Resources>
    ...
    <SequenceValue x:Key="sequenceValue"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

and set it as the DataContext of your TextBox and TextBlock

```
<TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource sequenceValue}" 
         Text="{Binding SequenceValueToKeep, FallbackValue='NNN', TargetNullValue='NNN', Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
        ... />

<TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource sequenceValue}" 
           Text="{Binding SequenceValuetoShow, FallbackValue=NNN, TargetNullValue=NNN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: I like the first solution. I tried the second and it did not work. Where should I put  that Datacontext in CounterSettings.xaml? I tried putting it beetween <Window.DataContext>.. .     </Window.DataContext>

Comment: @Doraemon You set the DataContext like every other Property on the Tag of your `Window`-Element. See my edit.

Comment: @Ackdary with some minor changes the first solution seems working. I still have not been able to have the second work though. I voted your answer up but I need to have 15 reputation before it is made public.

Comment: @Doraemon Do you get errors or anything for the second solution?

Comment: I just cannot make it work. I make the static object SequenceValueObj but I have not been able to have it take and return a string.